# how to properly compile c++ code with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have the following basic cpp code with pybind11:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

Here are the steps I followed (I am using visual studio 17 without python modules, I have python separately in anaconda envs):

- I manually added pybind11 header in the project's additional include directories.
- I set the target as x64 and Release
- I simply compiled the file, that created an object "example.obj" in the release directory
- I added the object file in a directory that is included in pythonpath
- tried import example in python, it gives no module named example error

The documentation in pybind11 does not specify which file types the compiler should generate, is it supposed to be a library file or dll? Are there any special steps to be followed other than this?

Comment: An object file is not enough, you need to build a dynamic library. Additionally, you need to provide the correct compiler flags and use a specific file name for the produced library. Are you able to use CMake? It can create the correct visual studio project files for you. Using pybind11 from CMake is really simple (4 lines), see https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/compiling.html#building-with-cmake

Comment: also, I simply installed pybind11 using pip, and included the header file from there (does this work?). Also in the cmake, in the example, it includes a subdirectory which is a clone of the whole pybind 11 project, do I have to include that in the cmake? it seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I would like to echo @pschill's answer:

Try using a supported / documented build toolchain *first*, then try to do something off the beaten path:

https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/compiling.html

I would suggest that you use CMake, try a subset of your example code, and then build your library with verbose options (e.g. `make VERBOSE=1`) to see what includes get added, and how the targets are generated.

If you still want to keep your non-CMake workflow, then you can port the relevant flags over to VS2017.

(That being said, CMake may have options to generate VS2017 project files.)

Comment: Actually earlier I did not know what file types python's import statement actually reads, I also didn't know that it requires this to be compiled as a library file, after visual studio generates the dll, it can simply be renamed to change the extension to ".pyd", and it works...(which is why in my question I asked what file types does an import statement read, and if I need to produce a dll etc)

Comment: Yup, quite understood! That could've been gleaned either from running it with the documented build system, or from perusing other CPython extension docs relevant to MSVC.

Comment: BTW If you have the answer yourself, you may want to consider posting and accepting it!